# Display Search box on an external list

Tags: 2013, external-content-type, external-list

I have an external list on a sharepoint site, from a BDC connector on sharepoint 2013. I want an inline Search box so that a search can be done on that list only. When i go into the web part and select 'Display Search box' , i think click apply it then the tick box goes. So does this mean i cannot add an Display search box on an external list ? If so thats poor. I dont have a problem with the search and it crawls the external content type fine. Any advice ?